# tomcat 9 error 405 in all resources

Tags: hibernate, jsp, tomcat

After configuring my server to work with jndi everytime i deploy i get 405 and when access a jsp of my project all the includes and resources are mark as 405, css, javascript all, and i dont any clue of what could happend i add the server.xml

```
  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    <Resource auth="Container" 
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
  maxActive="120" 
  maxIdle="10" 
  maxWait="5000" 
  name="jdbc/abc" 
  password="" 
  poolPreparedStatements="true" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="" 
  username=""/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

      <Context docBase="abc" path="/abc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:abc"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

is there any error on my configuration? another thing i can think is that i had a java class in the default package to test connectivity with my server althought i already deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another tomcat server and it works